# Removing outliers from groups in Panda DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am getting stuck with trying to group then filter data. Say I have a data set like below - but larger. I found useful answers here for removing data based on z-scores, but not in the case where I have to take subsets into account.

```
Answer,Month,Person
5,2,Bob
5,2,Bob
14,2,Bob
5,2,Bob
5,2,Bob
5,2,Bob
5,2,Cerys
15,2,Cerys
15,2,Cerys
5,3,Bob
5,3,Bob
```

For instance I can use the code like below

```
df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df["Answer"])) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

But I need to filter into sets by person for each month, then apply this code.
What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for `zscore` per groups:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['Month','Person'])['Answer'].transform(stats.zscore).abs() < 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that I should use the transform keyword there.